# UINavbar item shrinks to corner in ios 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I am trying to add a navigation bar item to navigation bar in xib. But it works fine for ios 7 but, in ios 8.1 it shrinks to corner to the border.How much ever i try to put in right place. Can anyone tell is this a bug in ios 8.1 or could anyone help me fixing this issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a work around its not perfect answer because it has disadvantages:(the push area for a user get smaller)

```
- (void)navigationBar 
{
[ARNStylessetNavigationBarTransparent          

:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[backBtn setAttributedTitle:whatEveryoulike];
[backBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(popBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 33);
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 33)];
backButtonView.bounds = CGRectOffset(backButtonView.bounds, 10, 10);
[backButtonView addSubview:backBtn];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

 }
```

you will need to add it programatically.
I think that the best way is to costumeze navigation bar.